# Very simple set value of array cell, program very slow when he writes on specify column

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I am using a continuous and old professional program.  My program builds several simple data arrays and writes the array to an excel cell like this:

```
Sheets("toto").Cells(4,i) = "blabla"
```

But for one value of `i`, the write time is very long and I don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
...
For No_Bug = 0 To Indtab - 1
    If mesComments(No_Bug) <> "" Then
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 1) = Ligne_Bug - 5
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 2) = mesID_Test(No_Bug)
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 3) = mesResultats(No_Bug)
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 4) = mesComments(No_Bug)
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 5).FormulaLocal = mesScreens(No_Bug)
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 6) = 2 'If I comment only this line, the programm is fast, ifnot the programm is very slow (~1, 2 secondes per loop), What the hell ??? xD
        Sheets(feuille_LBT).Cells(Ligne_Bug, 7) = 1
End If 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this cell referenced from other cells? Check if any complicated computations related with this cell.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I check if this Cell is referenced from other cells ? Im a poor newbies... Is there a simple way with visual basic to do that ? The program is "big" and the Excel contains several worksheets (maybe an another Sheet who 'listen' the column ?

Comment: I find the reference =) from a Graphic sheets ... Thanks for show the way Anefeletos =)